# Access remotely for WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I Want to let my website access to my WAMP server database remotely in Joomla CMS

Here is what I have:

- Server with public IP xxx.xxx.xx.xx
- connecting with another server by : 192.168.0.3

On this server I have installed WAMP Server, and I have installed Joomla CMS on external hosting and want to link Database to my WAMP.

What I could not to do is how can set host name and database information in configuration.php?

I have tried:

```
var $host = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/phpmyadmin';
var $user = 'user1';
var $password = 'password';
var $db = 'dbname';
```

But didn't work :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`$host` should be the hostname or ip address of the computer running the MySQL server, not the URL to the PHPMyAdmin client web application.

(You also need to ensure that the MySQL server is listening on TCP/IP and you have a user account on it with permission to be accessed from the remote machine).

Answer (score 0):

The problem may reside in so called remote `MySQL` login, you need to consult your hosting company, because, by default, all remote `MySQL` access is disabled, that is, attempt to access the database from host, different than `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

It is a usually an option in your administration panel, for example in `cPanel` it is called `Remote Database Access Hosts`, then you add a host(s), (% wildcard is allowed, it means any remote computer can access the `MySQL` remotely).

Comment: Thanks for your time, It's dedicated server and I have remote desktop access for it, Can you explain how can I configure MySQL for remote access, in detail please, if you have a time.

Comment: It is a usually an option in your administration panel, it depends on what type of administration you have installed, hard to tell in blind.